# Другая компоновка в классе-потомке

Tags: c++, qt, layout

Здравствуйте. Есть класс ComparisionTable, наследуемый от QWidget с виджетами: два QLabel и один QTableWidget.

Была компоновка прописана в конструкторе:

```
QVBoxLayout *pVBox  = new QVBoxLayout();
pVBox->addWidget(lblIS, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
pVBox->addWidget(lblOS, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
QHBoxLayout *pHBox  = new QHBoxLayout(this);
pHBox->addWidget(pTable);
pHBox->addLayout(pVBox);
this->setLayout(pHBox);
```

Нужно создать класс PairwiseComp, который будет наследоваться от вышенаписанного класса, только добавить еще один QLabel и нужные для него методы. 
Создал:

```
PairwiseComp::PairwiseComp(ComparisionTableData data, QString name, QWidget *parent)
    : ComparisionTable(data, parent)
{
    lblName     = new QLabel(this);
    lblName->setText("<font color=blue>"+name+"</font>");
```

И надо будет компоновку поменять. Как можно поменять компоновку? Просто добавлять в конструктор не вариант.

Comment: Просто в классе ComparisionTable не делайте компановку в конструкторе, а сделайте ее в виде отдельной виртуальной функцией. Тогда все методы сохранятся. А в наследуемом классе переопределите ее с новой компановкой.

Comment: @Madisson создавал. Делал виртуальную функцию, переопределял. Но все равно сначала запускается компоновка с родительского класса, а потом идет и из переопределенного, только ещё и с ошибкой, мол уже есть слой.

Answer (score 0):

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

namespace Ui {
class Test;
}

class Test : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Test(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();

    virtual void DrawScreen();
    ~Test();

private:
    Ui::Test *ui;
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "ui_test.h"

Test::Test(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Test)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void Test::DrawScreen()
{
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    QLabel *l1 = new QLabel("1234");
    QLabel *l2 = new QLabel("5678");
    lay->addWidget(l1);
    lay->addWidget(l2);
    setLayout(lay);
    show();
}

Test::~Test()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

pairwisecomp.h

```
#ifndef PAIRWISECOMP_H
#define PAIRWISECOMP_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include "test.h"


class PairwiseComp : public Test
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PairwiseComp(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void DrawScreen();
    ~PairwiseComp();
};

#endif // PAIRWISECOMP_H
```

pairwisecomp.cpp

```
#include "pairwisecomp.h"

PairwiseComp::PairwiseComp(QWidget *parent) : Test(parent)
{

}

void PairwiseComp::DrawScreen()
{
    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *l1 = new QLabel("1234");
    QLabel *l2 = new QLabel("5678");
    QLabel *l3 = new QLabel("1234");
    lay->addWidget(l1);
    lay->addWidget(l2);
    lay->addWidget(l3);
    setLayout(lay);
    show();
}

PairwiseComp::~PairwiseComp()
{

}
```

Вот этот пример вполне себе работоспособен. Изменяйте что и как вам нужно.